# How can I use fct_relabel but maintain original factor levels? Or how can I set factor levels in R with partial string matches?

Tags: r, factors, levels, forcats

I'm trying to use `fct_relabel()` from `forcats` to relabel my factor to include the factor name and the number of rows situated with it, but when I use the function, it completely changes the levels that I set to the order the columns appear. How can I override this? My original names are consistent (e.g., the animal names), but the counts will vary. As a result, I can't rely on manually releveling by the new labels name, unless I can somehow do a partial match (e.g., the label name doesn't fully match but contains cat).

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

test <- tibble(animal = factor(c("cat", "dog", "pig"), levels = c("dog", "pig", "cat")),
               n = c(100, 10, 5),
               animal_num = fct_relabel(animal, ~paste(animal, "N =", n)))

levels(test$animal) #original, correct levels
levels(test$animal_num) #levels should be "dog N = 10", "pig N = 5", "cat N = 100"
```

I'm also not married to having to use fct_relabel, but preference will be given to a tidyverse solution. Thank you!

**Update with example that has repeating values**

```
test <- tibble(animal = factor(c("cat", "dog", "pig", "cat", "dog"),
                               levels = c("dog", "pig", "cat")),
               n = c(100, 10, 5, 100, 10),
               animal_num = fct_relabel(animal, ~ paste(animal[order(animal)],
                                                        "N=", n[order(animal)])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `levels`

```
test <- tibble(animal = factor(c("cat", "dog", "pig"),
             levels = c("dog", "pig", "cat")),
               n = c(100, 10, 5),
       animal_num = fct_relabel(animal, 
     ~ paste(levels(animal), "N=", n[match(levels(animal), animal)])))
```

-output

```
> levels(test$animal)
[1] "dog" "pig" "cat"
> levels(test$animal_num)
[1] "dog N= 10"  "pig N= 5"   "cat N= 100"
```

Comment: thanks! This works for the practice set that I uploaded, but out of curiosity, is there a way to modify the code so it works for repeats. When I use it on my real dataset, there's multiple rows that say "cat", for instance, but when I run this, it says  "Error: `new_levels` must be the same length as `levels(f)`: expected 3 new levels, got 5."  If not, no worries because it answer the question I posted.

Comment: @J.Sabree Sorry, i thought it didn't have repeats.  Updated the code with `order`

Comment: no worries, I appreciate your help! Unfortunately, the modification makes the same error. Also, as I'm reading the code, I want to make sure I understand how its working--rather than pasting the exact string of animals, levels() has it paste its string (along with the level). Then, n[order(animals), looks up the order for the specific row? Is that right? It's so ingenious.

Comment: @J.Sabree The new code shouldn't have the same error because the length is now correct.  Can you update with a new example that shows error

Comment: I updated the problem with my new edits

Comment: @J.Sabree try the update.  It works in both examples.  The earlier one was correct, but i failed to change the `n` to include only the corresponding values for the `levels`

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you! To check my understanding, paste(animals) only pasted the characters from animal, but paste(levels(animal)) works by pasting the string and keeping the implicit level. The n[] portion is grabbing the n value that is a match between that current level within the animal column. Is that a correct way to interpret your code? Thanks again!

Comment: @J.Sabree In the documentation, it says `.fun - A function to be applied to each level. Must accept one character argument and return a character vector of the same length as its input`  The key is that it is not applied on the entire data, but on the `levels`.  Thus, we have to assume that the `n` column also have the same values for the corresponding levels of 'animal'.  Thus, `match` returns the position index of first match to extract the `n` values to be used in `paste`.  The `levels` return a `character` class object

Comment: @J.Sabree the documentation is not that clear, so I had to re-read couple of times